# cron.xml - validating error

Tags: java, google-app-engine

My cron.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cronentries>
 <cron>
   <url>/myURL</url>
   <description>Backup data 02 times per day</description>
   <schedule>every 12 hours</schedule>
   <timezone>America/New_York</timezone>
   <target>ah-builtin-python-bundle</target>
 </cron>
</cronentries>
```

When I upload my application to gae, I get an error message:

> An internal error occurred during: "Deploying App to Google". XML
>   error validating
>   /Users/Aptos/Documents/workspace/App/war/WEB-INF/cron.xml against
>   /Users/Aptos/appengine-java-sdk-1.7.0/docs/cron.xsd

cron.xsd file:

http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/java/docs/cron.xsd?r=109

**Solution** :  If the url element contains the special XML characters &, <, >, ', or ", you should escape them.

 Thank you very much

Comment: The XML looks valid, can you post the /Users/Aptos/appengine-java-sdk-1.7.0/docs/cron.xsd file?

Comment: @ShayErlichmen i've added cron.xsd file as your request

Comment: If you answer your own question, you can add it as a regular answer and accept it instead of editing your question. It helps readability.

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra tag :target (the last tag), this tag does not appear in the XSD.

Answer (score 1):

At least in the file you link to there is no target element in the cron element.
It looks like you have an old xsd file the latest xsd look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="cronentries" type="cronentries-Type"/>

  <xs:complexType name="cronentries-Type">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element type="cron-Type" name="cron" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="cron-Type">
    <xs:all>
      <xs:element type="xs:string" name="url"/>
      <xs:element type="xs:string" name="description" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element type="xs:string" name="schedule"/>
      <xs:element type="xs:string" name="timezone" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element type="target-Type" name="target" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:all>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:simpleType name="target-Type">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:pattern value="[a-z\d\-]{1,100}"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>

</xs:schema>
```

Comment: i have updated the xsd file to the latest file, but the error still occurs, I use online tool to validate and it says that my root element is not well formed :(

Answer (score 0):

The XSDs of these AppEngine configuration files are "namespaceless" (i.e. no targetNamespace compare with appengine-web.xsd's xs:schema), so you have to declare it as such:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cronentries xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="https://googleappengine.googlecode.com/svn-history/r109/trunk/java/docs/cron.xsd">
 <cron>
   <url>/myURL</url>
   <description>Backup data 02 times per day</description>
   <schedule>every 12 hours</schedule>
   <timezone>America/New_York</timezone>
   <target>ah-builtin-python-bundle</target>
 </cron>
</cronentries>
```

Also note that you have to use the raw version of the file:

https://googleappengine.googlecode.com/svn-history/r109/trunk/java/docs/cron.xsd

instead of the browser version:

https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/java/docs/cron.xsd?r=109